# Azure AD SAML authentication signing certificate change

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

We uses Azure AD for the SAML Authentication process. Azure is set up as the trust provider using the Federated Metadata that is published by Microsoft here: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml, we configure X509Certificate value in our system to validate the trust so to authenticate the login. We observe the signing certificate changes, that incurs to the change in the certificate value in turns leads to login issues on our system.

Any clue to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does signing cert change in turns? It's weird. How many cert in SAML siging certificate? The Cert which status is Active is what you're using. If you have mutiple cert, try to deleter other inactive certs.

Comment: I believe this certificate is changed on Microsoft azure side which is beyond our control, is this the similar process to jwt token singing certificate rotation?

Comment: I see. You mean that signing keys in Azure AD rollover, right?

Comment: Exactly issue is we can only configure one fixed value in our system for the key if it changing obviously we need to know a way to predict and change with it

Comment: This is changed by Azure. It will affect your application indeed. So, What  I suggest is adding the necessary logic to handle key rollover automatically for your application

Comment: How should I code this logic then, any endpoint I can call to get the updated certificate?

Comment: There is two ways: 1. Adding adding the necessary logic to handle key rollover automatically for your application. 2. If your application doesn't support automatic rollover , you will need to establish a process that  periodically monitors Azure AD's signing keys and performs a manual rollover accordingly.

Comment: It depends on what kind of your application.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover#how-to-assess-if-your-application-will-be-affected-and-what-to-do-about-it

Comment: Any schedule we should expect the certificate change?

Comment: Currently, Azure doesn't have notification for this signing key rollover. I also came across this issue. I have reported this issue to Azure PG Team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.This is changed by Azure. It's called [Signing key rollover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover).  It will affect your application indeed.

> For security purposes, Azure AD’s signing key rolls on a periodic
> basis and, in the case of an emergency, could be rolled over
> immediately. Any application that integrates with Azure AD should be
> prepared to handle a key rollover event no matter how frequently it
> may occur. If it doesn’t, and your application attempts to use an
> expired key to verify the signature on a token, the sign-in request
> will fail.

**How to resolve this:**

I understand what you mean and why. But currently, **Azure doesn't have notification for this signing key rollover**. I also came across this issue. Acutlly, **the best resolved method is make my application to handle key rollover  automatically by code**.Here is some [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover#how-to-assess-if-your-application-will-be-affected-and-what-to-do-about-it).

Otherwise, you need to write scripts to monitor the chagnes if your application does not support automatic rollover .[This GitHub repository](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-powershell-tokenkey) contains scripts and instructions on how to do this.

I have  reported this issue to the Azure PG Team.

Hope this helps！