# Azure AD Signing Keys for JWT

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

When you use Open ID connect with Azure AD, the JWT issued token (id token) is signed with an asymmetric key. I saw the public key to verify that signature is available in the metadata file, https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys. However, I couldn't find any documentation about how those keys are generated. How can you change the keys that are available there or how can I specify a different key to sign the JWTs for my tenant ?

Comment: see if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover

Comment: that doc does not say anything about how the keys are generated. I guess this is something handled by Microsoft, and not by the tenant.

Answer (score 4):

All sources and information suggests that this certificate roll over is done by Azure AD them self. Consumers are not able to do a manual roll over or put a certificate of their preference. This claim is supported by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638670/azure-ad-saml-authentication-signing-certificate-change) answer. Also, please check this [press release](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/upcoming-azure-active-directory-certificate-rollover-august-15-2016/) which mention a roll over happened in 2016

From your end you must be be ready to accept a rollover any time. Best practice is to fetch key information through discovery document. This is explained in the [openid connect documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc) piece of documentation, only way how to have your own signing key for your application, is custom claims mapping. Although description is very vague and instructions how to do it are scarce.